# How to use not equal in if condition when comparing two strings

Tags: java, string

I want to fail if state does not equal to "Running" and status does not equal to "OK"
I am using this but the code is going inside the if block even though the state is Running and status is ok

```
    if (!(state.equals("RUNNING")) && (status.equals(" OK")))
    {
Assert.fail();
}
```

I used this also

```
if ((state != ("RUNNING")) && (status !=(" OK")))
```

But this is also not working

Comment: Off topic but is it really " OK" you want to use and not "OK"?

Comment: "even though the state is Running **and** status is ok" - it can't be both at the same time. Or did you mean like `"RUNNING OK"` String? Then you should use `contains()` instead of `equals()`.

Comment: why do you use `!` and `equals(..)` in the first case but `!=` in the second?

Comment: How can I make it fail then 
and I mean and condition 
it should not be running and should not be OK
then it should fail

Comment: *"I want my scenario to fail if either state is not Running or status is not OK. It should fail if either of them does not suffice."* -> `state.equals("RUNNING") && status.equals("OK")`

Comment: @akuzminykh you're missing some `!`s in your conditions

Comment: @akuzminykh I want not equals

Comment: Count the `(`and `)`. And see on which the `!` is applied

Comment: @jhamon  because i was not getting expected result from first so tried the second way

Comment: @joshua Take your first code example and make sure it fits the the first sentence in your question, you are halfway there. _state does not equal to "Running" and status does not equal to "OK"_

Comment: related: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @jhamon  is this fine
if (!((getstate.equals("RUNNING")) && (gethealth.equals(" OK"))))

Comment: Does it look like what you tried to do on the second case? Did you tried that? Do you know boolean algebra?

Comment: Yes I tried that
And I am not able to figure out the way what operator to use for this and where to use.

Comment: @Joshua see my previous comment.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  I tried but I am not getting where to put not equal to the operator while comparing.

Comment: @akuzminykh I understood at the beginning we have to use! and parenthesis should cover both the condition 
Will it be like this
if(! state.equals("RUNNING") && status.equals("OK"))

Comment: @akuzminykh
These two are working
~~~
  if (!getstate.equals("RUNNING") && gethealth.equals(" OK"))
 if ((!getstate.equals("RUNNING")) && (!gethealth.equals(" OK")))
~~~

Answer (score 4):

1. Double-check your parenthesis, the `status` check is not negated properly
2. Remove the leading space in `" OK"`
3. *"...the state is Running and status is ok"*, then you might want to use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`

So, all in all:

```
if (!state.equalsIgnoreCase("RUNNING") && !status.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")) 
{
    Assert.fail();
}
```

Furthermore, you cannot use `!=` to compare String objects.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should step back and make a simple test case.

```
static public void test( String running, String status){
    return !"RUNNING".equals(running) && !" OK".equals(status);
}
```

Now have a main.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println( test( "fail", " OK") );
    System.out.println( test( "RUNNING", "fail) );
    System.out.println( test( "this one", "is true") );
}
```

If you like using extra parenthesis to be clearer then the condition can be changed to.

```
 ( !"RUNNING".equals(running) ) && ( !" OK".equals(status) );
```

I use the "String".equals form because it removes the chance of an NPE but it isn't necessary.

To use this criteria in an if statement.

```
if( ( !"RUNNING".equals(running) ) && ( !" OK".equals(status) ) ){
    //do something.
} else{
    //do something else.
    System.out.println(running + ", " + status);
}
```

Comment: Can I not use if the condition for this comparison ?

Comment: @joshua yes you can, I just separated this to isolate the condition. I think you have the concept but you've muddled it a bit with the fact your conditions are true when the values are not equal. So I've set it up to make a little truth table.

Comment: if ( !state.equals("RUNNING") ) && ( !status.equals("OK") )
will this work?

Comment: @joshua you're missing a parenthesis, so it is not correct.

Comment: check this
is this right
if (!getstate.equals("RUNNING") && gethealth.equals(" OK"))

Comment: These both are fine right?

if (!getstate.equals("RUNNING") && gethealth.equals(" OK"))
   if ((!getstate.equals("RUNNING")) && (!gethealth.equals(" OK")))

Comment: @joshua why are you asking me if it's correct? You can use a compiler and test it out. The first one looks good, the second one looks the same with more parenthesis. Also naming a variable 'getState' is not good practice. The variable should probably be `state` and then you would have a method, `public String getState()` which would return the value of the variable.

Comment: @joshua https://ideone.com/rCHjdq you can try the code here, and play around with the conditions.